# Fetch specific columns dynamically

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive, hibernate-reactive

I have the following User entity:

```
public class User extends PanacheEntityBase{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DataIdGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;

    public String name;
    public String location;

    public int age;
}
```

I also have the following endpoint: '/user', with a 'select' query parameter where you provide the column names you want to receive. It should be possible to select any combination of columns like:  `/user?select=id,name`, `/user?select=id,age`, `/user?select=name,age`, `/user?select=age,name`

Based on the 'select' query I want to use a projection to get the selected columns only. Currently I'm using the query to create the following query fe: `/user?select=id,name` to `SELECT d.id, d.name FROM User d`, however I need the DTO to be dynamic based on the columns provided too.

Currently I have the following projection where UserDTO is a class with id and name attributes. This works fine, but if I change any parameter I need a different DTO.

```
// This variable is dynamically created based on query parameters
String query = 'SELECT d.id, d.name FROM User d'
return User.find(query).project(UserDTO.class).list();
```

Is it possible to make this projection DTO class more dynamic, so it supports all combinations?

Comment: JPA/Hibernate supports tuple projection, so you can extract a generic resultset as an object with name and type checking.
IDK if Panache supports tuple projection (using `project(Tuple.class)`) but I don't think so (you are free to ask in a quarkus github discussion thread).

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-tuple-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the Panache API is not flexible enough at the moment to do what you are asking.

But you could use the Hibernate Reactive API without Panache:

```java
@Inject
Mutiny.SessionFactory sf;

public Uni<List<Tuple>> find(String query) {
   return sf.withSession(session ->
       session.createQuery(query, Tuple.class).getResultList()
   );
}
```

Once you have the `Tuple`, you can convert it to the type you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have your solution at the JPA layer. The trick is to serialize only the requested information back from your endpoint.

You can project onto a `UserDTO` that has **all** the fields of your entity that you would ever want to expose as nullable values (for example, use the same structure, but use `Integer` instead of `int` for the `age`). I think you would need to create constructors on this DTO for all the combinations of values you would want (each constructor would leave the other values as `null`).

Then you can annotate your DTO as `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` to have the Jackson serializer produce only the non-null fields in the response from your endpoint.

And I hope it goes without saying, but I'll say it anyway: Since you are allowing user generated input to modify your query, you should sanitize the inputs for this.